# aligned_alloc not found for clang

Tags: macos, clang, c11

I am running the following version of clang on a Mac OS X host:

```
$ clang -v
Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.42)
```

I have some code that uses the `aligned_alloc()` C11 function to allocate an aligned chunk of memory.

I am compiling my binary with the `-std=c11` flag:

```
...
clang -g -Wall -Wextra -mavx -std=c11 -D__USE_POSIX -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDINT_MACROS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -O2 -c my_binary.c -o my_binary.o; \
clang -g -Wall -Wextra -mavx -std=c11 -D__USE_POSIX -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDINT_MACROS -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE=1 -O2 my_binary.o -o my_binary -lm; \
...
```

I am including `stdlib.h` and adding POSIX flags. From `my_binary.h`:

```
...
#ifndef _POSIX_C_SOURCE
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#endif /* getline() support */

#ifndef _XOPEN_SOURCE
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#endif /* aligned_alloc() support */

#include <stdlib.h>
...
```

I get the following compilation warning:

```
my_binary.c:245:15: warning: implicit declaration of function 'aligned_alloc' is invalid in C99 [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
s->data = aligned_alloc(32, s->n * sizeof(*s->data));
```

Which follows with this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_aligned_alloc", referenced from:
      _bs_initialize_signal_avx in my_binary.o
      _bs_copy_signal_avx in my_binary.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [build] Error 1
```

What am I doing incorrectly with clang, such that compilation ignores the `std` C11 flag?

I am able to compile without errors on a CentOS 7 (Linux) host with gcc 5.3.0 and glibc 2.22.

Comment: In fact, C11 support comes in two parts, language and library. It seems that your compiler is up-to-date w.r.t to the language, but your platform is lacking C11 library support. So this is more a question of your OS installation and if Apple would be willing to update its C library to C11.

Comment: So when I read Clang docs indicating C11 is the default standard for compilation, and even if I manually set that as the standard, Clang does not support C11?

Comment: No, your OS doesn't support C11, `clang` is for nothing in all of that. Last time I looked OS X was far behind concerning their support for standards. Their POSIX version also was quite old.

Comment: If I'm reading this C11 reference correctly (https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc), `aligned_alloc` is required to fail if the specified alignment is not supported by the implementation, whereas `posix_memalign` is guaranteed to work for any alignment that is a power of two and a multiple of `sizeof(void *)`. Doesn't answer your question, but might help in the sense that you could try using `posix_memalign` instead, which has worked well for me in some code I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

The macOS 11.1 SDK definition for aligned_alloc states this API isn’t available until macOS 10.15. 10.14 and lower will need an alternate solution for C code needing this function.

C++ programs can use a newer Clang/LLVM libc++ (like Clang 12+) and link to that library instead of defaulting to the system libc++.1.dylib.